# What's the difference between cat and ypcat?

Tags: shell, unix, cat

What's the difference between:

> cat /etc/passwd

and

> ypcat passwd

? What is ypcat exactly?

Why do I get this:

> ypcat: can't get local yp domain: Local domain name not set

when running

> ypcat passwd.

Comment: This is not a programming-related question. It's off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ypcat` shows the data from the *NIS database*, which may not be on your computer.  That holds *network* accounts (which allow you to log into various computers on your network).  It is named with a "yp" prefix since the original programs were referred to as "yellow pages" (until Sun and others were told to stop doing that — by the phone company).

`cat` (of course) shows only data from a file on your computer, which lists *local* accounts.

Further reading:

- [28.4. Network Information System (NIS)](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-nis.html) (FreeBSD handbook)
- [Using NIS](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~jack/ifsm498d/llb-nis.html)  ([Introduction to Unix Systems Administration, IFSM 498B](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~jack/ifsm498d/))

Answer (score 1):

The cat command is used to concatenate and display the contents of the given files.

ypcat on the other hand

> prints out the Network Information Services (NIS) map you specify with the MapName parameter. You can specify either a map name or a map nickname. Because the ypcat command uses the NIS service, you do not need to specify a server

where NIS is

> The Network Information Service, or NIS (originally called Yellow Pages or YP) is a client–server directory service protocol for distributing system configuration data such as user and host names between computers on a computer network.

Read about ypcat here : http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds6/ypcat.htm

Read about NIS here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service